# Testing multiple threads waiting on condition_variables in a queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable

I am testing how to push objects waiting on  condition_variables in a queue. I want to execute the threads as per my wish because they will be in critical sections later. Nothing is printed from the threads, what could be wrong ?

```
mutex print_mu;

void print(function<void()> func)
{
    lock_guard<mutex> lock(print_mu);
    func();
}

unsigned int generate_id()
{
    static unsigned int id = 1;
    return id++;
}

class foo
{
    unsigned int id_;
    mutex mu_;
    condition_variable cv_;
    bool signal_;
    bool& kill_;
public:
    foo(bool kill) 
        :kill_(kill) 
        , signal_(false)
        , id_(generate_id())
    {
        run();
    }

    void set()
    {
        signal_ = true;
    }

    void run()
    {
        async(launch::async, [=]()
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> lock(mu_);
            cv_.wait(lock, [&]() { return signal_ || kill_ ; });

            if (kill_)
            {
                print([=](){ cout << " Thread " << id_ << " killed!" << endl; });
                return;
            }

            print([=](){ cout << " Hello from thread " << id_ << endl; });
        });
    }
};

int main()
{
    queue<shared_ptr<foo>> foos;
    bool kill = false;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        shared_ptr<foo> p = make_shared<foo>(kill);
        foos.push(p);
    }
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(2));

    auto p1 = foos.front();
    p1->set();
    foos.pop();

    auto p2 = foos.front();
    p2->set();
    foos.pop();

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(2));

    kill = true; // terminate all waiting threads unconditionally

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(2));

    print([=](){ cout << " Main thread exits" << endl; });

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a thread calls `std::condition_variable::wait`, it will block until another thread calls `notify_one` or `notify_all` on the same `condition_variable`.  Since you never call `notify_*` on any of your `condition_variables` they will block forever.

Your `foo::run` method will also block forever, since `std::future`'s destructor will block waiting for the result of a `std::async` call if it's the last `std::future` referencing that result.  Thus your code deadlocks: your main thread is blocked waiting for your async future to finish, and your async future is blocked waiting for your main thread to signal `cv_`.

(Also `foo::kill_` is a dangling reference.  Well, it would become one if `run` ever returned anyway.)

Comment: Nice catch. Thanks.